# Languages in vim

Tags: linux, vim, rhel-5

How to insert Hindi or Swedish characters in VIM

When I insert these words it appears as "......"

Comment: Not enough information. VIM can be run in a many ways: as GVIM locally or on foreign X Window server; as VIM locally in terminal or in terminal emulator or over ssh from other box. Problem could be in both input and output and without knowing what are they it is impossible to respond to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try `:dig` for a list of special chars which you can insert with `CTRL + K` and `:help dig` for explanation.
- Check if your font is able to display the special chars

Answer (score 2):

Vim has no problem with Unicode characters outside of ASCII. The problem is most likely to be found in either the font you use in Vim, or in the setup of your system.
To find out what isn't working, we need more information, such as

- What font are you using in Vim?
- what's the output of running `locale` in a terminal?
- What's the result when you try to write one of these swedish/hindi characters in a terminal, and in gedit?

Comment: Locale gives the following output 

[root@localhost site]# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: that answers one of the three questions I asked....

Comment: Since the locale settings look fine, my guess is that the font does not support these characters. Choose another font.